# How to best fix both warnings(old style c-function declaration isn't a prototype)

Tags: c, function-pointers, gcc-warning, function-prototypes

I was fixing some functions in a piece of someone else code that included a number of functions that took no arguments. 
They were declared as

```
return_type_t func();
```

instead of
    return_type_t func(void);

Then I found that a bunch of these were put in a array of structs with function pointers.
When I fixed the function pointer to take void it gave me another warning since 1 of the function took a char* instead of void ptr.

What's the best solution for this sort of thing without a large rewrite(as the code is complex I was mainly cleaning it up around the edges and wish to avoid changing how it flows)?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having a function declaration that doesn't have argument. It is even allowed by the specification.

Comment: Beware: "cleaning up" like this often introduces bugs as you subtly change types and function calls etc. In my experience doing so is a waste of time. I would add spaces, comments, additional unit tests, but no more!

Comment: It's not just the definition and/or declaration. It's also about usage.
How are the functions called? Are all functions invariably given a char* as a parameter when called?

Comment: It seems like only that one is passed an argument but I will check.

Answer (score 1):

The `struct` definition needs to list the correct function type in the member, there is no way around that if you want type safety.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the old-style declaration `return_type_t func()` doesn't mean that `func` takes no arguments, it means that the number and types of its arguments (if any) are not specified.  You cannot just assume that you can add `void` inside the parentheses.

Without seeing more of your code, my advice is to investigate each function separately and find out the correct number and types of parameters for each, and then fill out the prototype accordingly.

Comment: All but one of the functions in the array of structs take void

Comment: All right.  What's the problem with filling in the prototypes accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite all your prototype to take a char* and then cast to `(void) parameter` where the parameter is not usefull